# Analyse recorded audio file with Swift for speech to text

Tags: ios, swift, audio, speech-to-text

I'm able to record audio with Swift for iOS and play the recorded audio file. What I'm asking is if it is possible to check the recorded audio file for background noise & volume/decibel so I can decide that it is good enough for my speech to text framework. The framework is not the problem and I have researched all the available ones.

I'm curious if I can analyse the recorded audio file with AVFoundation or Accelerate Framework or any other framework to check if the audio file is good/clear enough to process with a speech to text framework.

I don't have a lot of audio knowledge but I've researched a bit and found out I can get the peak and average decibel values while recording but what about background noise?

Any information would be helpful about analysing a recorded audio file with Swift.

Comment: Please bear in mind that `swift` and `objective-c` are high level languages which you would hardly find on a serious program's DSP thread, which is running with real time priority. Why? Because all the comfortable stuff (allocating objects, memory management, polling & blocking, etc…) simply can't take place on the real time thread, unless you're looking for trouble. For the DSP code it is critical that it runs _fast_. So, you may write your UI or controller in `swift`, but the safest bet for the DSP part, such as SNR estimation would be dropping down to _plain-C_.

Answer (score 4):

SNR estimation is pretty well developed domain. You need to implement a voice activity detector which will separate noise from speech and then separately compute noise energy and signal energy and then calculate the ratio. This goes slightly beyond simple math though, you need to understand statistics to implement a reasonable algorithm like [Wada SNR](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~robust/Papers/KimSternIS08.pdf) which is implemented [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~robust/archive/algorithms/WADA_SNR_IS_2008/WadaSNR.tar.gz).

You will not be able to find the implementation of it in Swift, such software is usually implemented in C or Matlab, you will have to port the implementation.

Noise estimation is a minor problem compared to speech recognition, that involves much more advanced algorithms. It is probably better to consider existing package for speech recognition in Swift like [TLsphinx](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx) or  [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/2016/05/21/openears-and-swift/).

Comment: Thanks. So as far as I've searched there are no solutions for SNR or VAD in Swift/Objective-C available. The speech recognition is already working but thanks for the suggestions. I can analyse the average and peak power returned in dB's from the audioRecorder during recording so that's the only analysis I found for now.

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev I want to use wada snr. downloaded the folder you mentioned however, I don't know how to install it. could not find any documentation

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev I started a new question on similar matter